# Angular 9: Hashing files in assets folder during deployment

Tags: deployment, angular9

I am using Angular 9 and the angular.json file that include all my build process.

**Problem:**: I want to hash files inside my assets folder but only the files directly inside the wwwroot folder are hashed.

**Build section:**

```json
"build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
        "aot": true,
        "outputPath": "wwwroot",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "assets": [
            "src/favicon.ico",
            "src/assets",
            {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets/i18n",
                "output": "./assets/i18n/"
            },
            // i tried another option path just in case
            {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./i18n",
                "output": "./i18n/"
            }
        ],
        "styles": [
            "src/styles.scss",
            "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
    }
}
```

Note that I have no error during the build and my application is deployed successfully but my files content inside the assets folder are not hashed. Is there a reason why ?
Thank you